# D3.js custom axis labels and converging tick mark spacing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I currently have two separate x-axis set up so that I can display two sets of data while sharing the same y-axis. This is what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6ulv.jpg

**Is there a way I can customize the spacing and also converge 1-6 into one area, so that I can focus mostly on 7.1-7.4?** I've taken a look at ordinal scales, but not sure if that's the right approach since my data is still linear/numerical. This is what I would like to have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiiaC.jpg

Comment: two graphs side-by-side. one with x = [1-6], the other with x = [7.1-7.4]?  Or, use a log scale?

Comment: @Rhett I think the log scale would be the route to go, but the problem with that is that it'll still be forward-facing, as in a large area between 1-6, and a small area between 7.1-7.4. I want to be able to focus more on that latter part.

Comment: Ended up utilizing a rescale button to just rescale the axis when I want to focus on one set of data vs. the other. Only problem is that I can rescale the axis fine, but the data doesn't move.